# Whats the maximum amount of NFT-s per wallet that Opensea can handle?

Tags: nft, polygon

I have a project where we need to mint 2 Million NFT-s for  different users. One user will have most likely 20k-40k NFT-s in his wallet. NFT-s will be in Polygon chain.

Whats the maximum amount of NFT-s per wallet that Opensea/Rarible can handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not have a limit since they're basically a Blockchain explorer :) you can set any supply as big as you want :D

Answer (score 1):

Opensea does not have a preset limit on how many NFTs a wallet can hold. However, wallets with large amounts of NFTs may experience performance and speed issues.